# Maximum Value and Minimum value sorting via user input in Python

Tags: python

guys I wanted to sort a pre defined list in ascending and descending order of user input value. It suppose to take a max and min value from user and see those values in the list and then print in ascending and descending order. IDK how to use range function to achive this task so if some one can help please :D Here is the code that i DID and want to use that list

```
userInputMax = input("Please enter max value")
userInputMin = input("Please enter min value")

priceList = [399, 4369, 539, 288, 109, 749, 235, 190, 99, 1000]

print(priceList)
```

Output should be like if user says Maximum value is 1000 and min value is 99 so the output be like 99, 109, 235, 288, 399, 539, 749, 1000

Comment: What is that you need to print?

Comment: @DaniMesejo priceList i want to print according to user input in ascending order.

Comment: Please add the expected output, what would be input from the user and other details

Comment: So How i do that by entering a specified value ? @BrutusForcus

Comment: the user provides a min & max on a given list right? so if the user gives a max=300 and min=100 then do you only want priceList = [ 109,190,235,288]

Comment: @stacksideways YES!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?

```
try:
  max = int(input("Please enter max value: "))
  min = int(input("Please enter min value: "))
except ValueError:
  raise ValueError('Inserted value is not number')

priceList = [399, 4369, 539, 288, 109, 749, 235, 190, 99, 1000]
priceList.sort()

filtered_priceList = list(filter(lambda x: x < max and x > min, priceList))

print('resulted list is', filtered_priceList)
```

```
Please enter max value: 200
Please enter min value: 900
resulted list is [235, 288, 399, 539, 749]
```

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
I got this error, as you used hardcoded values but I want user input values

Comment: Love You bro :D You made it :D THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def condition(x,usermax,usermin):
    '''Define your arbitrarily
    complicated condition here'''
    return x<=usermax and x>=usermin

priceList = [399, 4369, 539, 288, 109, 749, 235, 190, 99, 1000]

# Filter out all elements that do
# not meet condition
filtered = [x for x in priceList if condition(x,userInputMax,userInputMin)]
filtered.sort()

print(filtered)
```